# Error when up the php-worker container (laradock lite)

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

```
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,312 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,312 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    |    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    |   at /var/www/wo-api/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php:24
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,313 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    |     20|  * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
php-worker_1    |     21|  *
php-worker_1    |     22|  * @deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface instead
php-worker_1    |     23|  */
php-worker_1    |   > 24| interface TranslatorInterface extends LocaleAwareInterface
php-worker_1    |     25| {
php-worker_1    |     26|     /**
php-worker_1    |     27|      * Translates the given message.
php-worker_1    |     28|      *
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,313 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,313 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    |    Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,313 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    |   at /var/www/wo-api/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php:24
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,314 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    |     20|  * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
php-worker_1    |     21|  *
php-worker_1    |     22|  * @deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface instead
php-worker_1    |     23|  */
php-worker_1    |   > 24| interface TranslatorInterface extends LocaleAwareInterface
php-worker_1    |     25| {
php-worker_1    |     26|     /**
php-worker_1    |     27|      * Translates the given message.
php-worker_1    |     28|      *
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    | 2020-05-26 16:17:15,314 DEBG 'laravel-worker_01' stdout output:
php-worker_1    |   Exception trace:
php-worker_1    | 
php-worker_1    |   1   Whoops\Run::handleError("Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)", "/var/www/wo-api/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php")
php-worker_1    |       /var/www/wo-api/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php:408
php-worker_1    |
```

My Dockerfile from php-worker:

```
FROM php:7.3.6-fpm-alpine3.9

RUN sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/' /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update --no-cache \
    && apk upgrade --no-cache \
    && apk add --no-cache build-base autoconf libmcrypt-dev supervisor \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apk del build-base autoconf

CMD ["supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf", "-e", "debug"]
```

And my supervisord.ini:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/wo-api/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
```

Everything in the normal configuration pattern that we can download in the laradock lite repository.

Does anyone know what this error means and how to solve it?
I'm using laravel 6 and this version of laradock with a plus to upload a vuejs application, but nothing has been removed, just added (front).

Comment: For the love of containers, don't do this. Prefer multiple container over a supervisor'ed container. See introduction of https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: thanks bro, i'll see that